# Binding styled ListBoxItem with RelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

- As seen from below DataTemplate, I have created listview of buttons.    I have specified Command and CommandParameter for this button. But    when these buttons are CanExecute and Execute methods are not fired.    Now if, I place a single button on the user control and bind the    command, the event fires. Why does this happen ?

> ```
>        <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlphabetsContainerStyle}" 
>               ItemsSource="{Binding Alphabets}"/>
>             <Button Command="{Binding Path=FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="A"/>   <!-- Works -->
>
>
>             <!-- Code in the Resource Dictionary File -->
>
>             <DataTemplate x:Key="AlphabetsTemplate">
>                     <Border>            
>                         <Button Content="{Binding}"  
>                                 Command="{Binding Path=FilterCommand}"
>                                 CommandParameter="A"/>                   <!-- Doesn't Work -->
>                     </Border>
>             </DataTemplate>
>
>             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="AlphabetsContainerStyle">
>                 <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AlphabetsTemplate}"/>
>             </Style>
> ```

***I have removed other setter properties and resources for keeping the codeview clean.*

- Secondly, how can I replace button with label and attach the ICommand    directly to the ListBoxItem?

> ```
>  <!-- Replacing Button with Label -->
> ```

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AlphabetsTemplate">
            <Border>            
                <Label Content="{Binding}"         <!-- Label Doesnt have Command Property -->
            </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

 <!-- How can I  set Command directly to ListBoxItem ?-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="AlphabetsContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AlphabetsTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For the Button case you should change the order of style and DataTemplate-

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AlphabetsTemplate">
        <Border>            
            <Button Content="{Binding}"  
                    Command="{Binding Path=FilterCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="A"/>                   <!-- Doesn't Work -->
        </Border>
</DataTemplate>    

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="AlphabetsContainerStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AlphabetsTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

For the Label, please specify your requirement.

Comment: The order is same as described by you, but I presented here in hierarchical order for better understanding. I am changing it for avoiding misconception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems FilterCommand is losing datacontext, specify ElementName where FilterCommand has been defined(eg. define X:Name to your window and provide it as Element )

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="A1">
    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="AlphabetsTemplate">
            <Border>
                <Button Content="{Binding}"  
                        Command="{Binding Path=FilterCommand, ElementName=A1}"
                        CommandParameter="A"/>               
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```